# Why two `{` is required here?

Tags: perl

```
$text =~ s/(cat|tomatoes)/ ${{ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> }}{$1} /ge;
```

And I can't replace `${{ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> }}{$1}` with `{ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> }->{$1}`,why?

**UPDATE**

```
  5 @array = qw<a b c d>;
  6 $ref = \@array;
  7 @{$ref} = qw<1 2 3 4>;
  8 #@$ref = qw<1 2 3 4>;//also works
  9 print "@array";
```

So it indicates neither `{}` nor `${}` is required to dereferencing,the `{}` is only required when ambiguity arises,and `$` only in scalar context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
${{ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> }}{$1}
```

is

```
my $ref = { qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> };
${ $ref }{$key}
```

The inner brackets form an anonymous hash constructor. It creates a hash, assigns the contents of the brackets to it, then returns a reference to it.

The outer brackets are part of the hash dereference. They can be omitted (e.g. `$$ref{$key}` instead of `${$ref}{$key}`) when unambiguous (e.g. when dereferencing a simple scalar), but this is not such a circumstance.

One can also dereference using the arrow notation, so one could also have used

```
{ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> }->{$1}
```

The difference is that the version being used is simply a variable lookup, so it doesn't require /e, while the latter is Perl code, so it does require /e.

---

If you had just

```
${ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> }{$1}
```

that would be the same as

```
${ "tomatoes" }{$1}
```

since qw() in scalar context returns the last value. That, in turn, is the same as

```
$tomatoes{$1}
```

(except that `use strict;` wouldn't allow it) and that's obviously not what you want.

Comment: @new_perl, I've added to my answer.

Comment: I've updated with what I'm doubting about above.Say,I need a final confirm of my conclusion.

Comment: @new_perl, "and $ only in scalar context" is wrong. See [Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=383504#deref_syntax)

Answer (score 2):

The outer brackets dereference the anonymous hash created by the inner brackets.

Update for clarification: The second format you use would work if you give the compiler a clue by putting a + in front of it:

`+{ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes }->{$1}`

Comment: @DavidO,I never heard that `{}` is used for dereference before.Is that true?

Comment: What does the additional `+` do?

Comment: In the case of `${{qw........`, the `${` dereferences the anonymous hash created with the anonymous hash constructor `{}`.  The second case is syntactically ambiguous to the compiler unless you give it a clue as to your intent.  The + causes the compiler to see the {} as an expression (a hash constructor) rather than a code block.

Comment: @DavidO,isn't `$` enough to derefefence it,like in the case `$$r{key}`,why is `${` mandated here?

Comment: @new_perl: ${} dereferences 'something'.  But it needs a reference to dereference.  The anonymous hash constructor {} nested in there creates a hash reference with, in your case, two elements inside it (2 key/value pairs).  Imagine `${[ qw/this that the other/]}[0]` or `${$some_scalar}`.  Hash, array, scalar; consistent behavior.

Comment: @DavidO, No, you need the arrow too. `{ ... }->{...}`

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks, I should have copied/pasted my quick test. ;) I'll update my post.  For the record, the OP may benefit from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927 (References Quick Reference)

Comment: @DavidO,I think it's not that `${` does the dereferencing,here `$` is there for scalar context,not for dereferencing,right?

Comment: @new_perl: No. You'll have to read through perldoc perlreftut and perldoc perlref.  Those docs should clarify it for you, but if not, feel free to ask.

Comment: @new_perl: Perhaps you should be posting the tests and asking what they mean, rather than assuming that they're proving that ${} doesn't dereference the reference contained within it.  Have you ever read perldoc perlreftut and perldoc perlref?

Comment: @DavidO ,see my update,it indicates that you don't need any special operator to do the dereferencing.

Comment: Your update uses `@{}` to dereference `$ref` as a whole array.  `${$ref}[0]` or `$ref->[0]` would take one element of that array.  An anonymous array is created with `[ qw/this that the other/ ]`, and can be dereferenced as follows: `@{ [ qw/this that the other / ] }` (the entire array), or as `${ [ qw/ this that the other / ] }[0]` (one element), or as `[ qw/this that the other/ ]->[0]` (one element).  Will you please read perlreftut?  I'm out. I've really been trying to help you.  Now it's time for the docs.

Comment: @DavidO,hey buddy,just calm down.What I pasted above just proves that you don't necessarily need `${` to dereference something, as indicated in that both `@{$ref} = qw<1 2 3 4>;` and `@$ref = qw<1 2 3 4>;` work .You may want to see the output of `print "@array";` to know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The Perl parser is getting mixed up about what you mean by the {} around qw.  Instead of using the curly braces to create a hash ref it sees the curly braces as creating a code block.  You can force {} to mean "create a hash" by putting a plus sign in front of it:

$text='The cat ate the bacon';
$text =~ s/(cat|tomatoes)/ +{qw(tomatoes cat cat tomatoes)}->{$1} /ge;
print "The text is now $text\n";

This prints "The text is now The tomatoes ate the bacon"

See the section on creating hash references here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html